# Google Play Open Testing link sharing gives errors

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I just finished the first version of my react native app and I've uploaded it to the google play store for open testing. However, I can't get a public link that anyone can download the app from to work.

I have used internal testing, closed testing and they both work ONLY IF I have testers added by email to my list.

The two links that are available from under the testers bar in Open Testing are "Join on android"

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.(Myapppname)

as well as "Join on the Web"
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.(Myappname).

The first link ONLY works if I am logged on to my main account (it shows "We're sorry, link is unavailable...etc)

and the second link says that the app doesn't exist or I am not added as a tester - but open testing should work without me manually adding new testers right?

I would very much appreciate any help on this.
Extra info:

App is "under review"

App has been uploaded today morning (been 9 hrs+ since uploading).

Comment: Did it work with you?

Answer (score 0):

probably the open testing version is under review.
you can check this out from Google Play console, from "**Releases overview**" in left menu.
just wait (it may take couple of days) and then it will work just fine.

Comment: my case is the same, and not, it's not in review. Other people can install the app